# How to coordinate bash profile with zsh

Tags: bash, shell, command-line

I recently switched my shell from bash to zsh. I had set up Anaconda via bash, but now that I'm running zsh as my default shell, I can't find conda or, more importantly, Jupyter. I've figured that to get access to Jupyter I can use `exec bash -l`, but that seems pointlessly temporary. I would rather access Jupyter locally from zsh. Is there some way to link zsh back to the bash configs?

Comment: You can put `source ~/.bashrc` in your `.zshrc` and similarly source `.bash_profile` from `.zprofile`

Comment: @thatotherguy Do you mean `~/.profile`? I saw no configs in either `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`. Either way it worked with `.profile`, put as an answer so I can credit you.

Comment: Whichever file you modified for bash that zsh currently doesn't read

Comment: @thatotherguy, ...assuming one is keeping them compatible, which often isn't possible. (I suppose one could put the portable parts up top and then `return` after a check for which shell one's actually in before entering the nonportable parts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since zsh can interpret most of bash, you can have it include the bash init files in its corresponding init files.

To do this, add e.g. the line `source ~/.bashrc` in `~/.zshrc`

Each shell has many different config files and they don't correspond 1:1, so look through and see which ones you want to link. For example, zsh login shells reads both `.zlogin` and `.zprofile`, while bash login shells read only the first available of `.bash_profile`, `.bash_login` and `.profile`

Comment: There are non-syntactic differences between `zsh` and `bash` that make this a dubious suggestion. There are also significant differences in commands that one might expect to see in these files, for instance `shopt` (`bash`) vs `setopt` (`zsh`).

Answer (score 0):

I was having an issue with `mysql: command not found` after I had set the PATH correctly in `.bash_profile`.

What worked great for me was the following:

1. Add `source ~/.bash_profile` to the first line of `~/.zprofile`
2. Restart Terminal